# Why do I need to click twice on textfield to invoke the function in Java Script right after refreshing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have the datetimepicker:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control datetimepicker" id='datetimepicker' name="appearanceDate0"/>
```

and since I cannot use id in my case I have to refer to it by class..
So when I write:

```
$("body").on("click", ".datetimepicker", function () {
                            $(this).datetimepicker({
        onChangeDateTime: logic,
        onShow: logic
    });
});
```

then after reloading the page I have to click twice on the textfield to invoke the datetimepicker. However, later on when I don't refresh the page I can click once and the picker appears. Why is it so and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".datetimepicker", function () {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            onChangeDateTime: logic,
            onShow: logic
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your element is not generated dynamically then you don't need the event delegation syntax as you have bound currently.

because you are initializing the datetimepicker in the click event. first it registers then you can use it. Solution is either you call it in a function or use a trailing click:

```
$("body").on("click", ".datetimepicker", function () {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        onChangeDateTime: logic,
        onShow: logic
    });
}).click();
```

another way using a function is:

```
function createdtp(elem){
    $(elem).datetimepicker({
       onChangeDateTime: logic,
       onShow: logic
    });
}
```

and call it:

```
$("body").on("click", ".datetimepicker", function (){
    createdtp(this);
});
```

Comment: thanks, I pasted your code but it didn't work, is there another solution? Thanks!

Comment: What about `$('.datetimepicker').click(function() {createdtp(this)});` ?

Comment: Actually I generate the elements dynamically, sorry for not mentioning that :(

Comment: @MattO'Connell that is what i mentioned at first line in the answer.

Comment: @randomuser1 make sure you don't put the code in any function to call it, it should be outside of function, sometimes it happens when you put the initialization in a global function.

Comment: @Jai, gotcha. That's what I thought but was confused when you did not use it in the example